# EmberJs: nested views

Tags: view, ember.js, nested, outlet

I have this view which can rotate a div element. Something like

```
<div class="rotatable">
    <div class="front">
         {{outlet front}}
    </div>
    <div class="back">
        {{outlet back}}
    <div>
</div>
```

Now I have this index template which contains two of these rotatable elements. Each rotatable elements has a different front and back. So it could look like this

```
<div id="index">
    {{#rotatable}}
        {{outlet front App.FrontView1}}
        {{outlet back App.BackView1}}
    {{/rotatable}}
    {{#rotatable}}
        <div>This should show up inside {{outlet front}}</div>
        {{outlet back App.BackView2}}
    {{/rotatable}}
</div>
```

This doesn't work of course, but how should this be done ?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this question was a little bit unclear. Anyway, the answer is given in this post

[EmberJs: how to use connectOutlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605384/emberjs-how-to-use-connectoutlet)